# Vue js undefined indificator

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I watched a video lesson on vueschool and repeated the code as the teacher. But it doesn't work for me, and it works for him. In the browser console, it shows that there is no template indexer, but why does it all work?
HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <p>Просто текст</p>
        <click-counter></click-counter>
        <click-counter></click-counter>
        <click-counter></click-counter>
    </div>
<script scr="vue.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

vue js

```
Vue.component ('click-counter', {
        template: "<button @click="count++">{{count}}</button>",
        data() {
            return {
                count: 0
            }
        }
    })
    new Vue ({
        el: "#app"
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

In the component template, please use `'` quotes to wrap the click function. Since you are using double quotes to wrap button, the same cannot be used in it which tends to close the first one.

Please find below the code

```js
Vue.component('click-counter', {
  template: "<button @click='count++'>{{count}}</button>",
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  }
})
new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.0/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<click-counter/>
</div>
```

Comment: What has changed in the JavaScript code? This solution does not work

Comment: template: "<button @click='count++'>{{count}}</button>", check this line quotes carefully. And see the snippet is working

Comment: Sorry, all okey, ty

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
"<button @click="count++">{{count}}</button>"
```

Give this:

```
"<button @click='count++'>{{count}}</button>"
```

Make sure that, you have import `vuejs` in your file.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```